Continuity regarding integration over indicator function
i have problems proving the following:
Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open, bounded and simply connected set. Let $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded function with $|\nabla f(x)|>0$ almost everywhere in $D$.
Furthermore, the function $g:[a, b] \rightarrow [0, |D|]$ is defined by $g(c)=\int_D \chi_{f+c\leq0}(x) dx$, where $\chi_{f+c\leq0}$ is the indicator function of the set $\{f+c\leq0\}$.
Now, i want to proof that the function $g$ is continuous.
My idea is to perform the following splitting:
$g(c)=\int_D \chi_{f+c\leq0}(x) dx = \int_D \chi_{f+c < 0}(x) dx + \int_D \chi_{f+c=0}(x) dx = g_{<}(c) + g_{0}(c) = g_{<}(c),$
where $g_{0}(c)$ vanishes because of $|\nabla f(x)|>0$ almost everywhere in $D$. Now, the constant and therefore continuous function $h(c) = |D|$ for all $c\in[a, b]$ can be written as $h(c)=g_{<}(c) + g_{>}(c)$ with $g_{>}(c) = \int_D \chi_{f+c > 0}(x) dx$. Now, my argument would be: We have that $g_{<}(c)$ and $g_{>}(c)$ are lower semicontinuous and therefore also continuous due to the continuity of $h$.
My questions now are: Is this last argument correct and second how do i proof the semicontinuity?
I would be grateful for some help and thanks in advance!
